# What does the phrase "loci citati" mean in citations?

Tags: citations, terminology, academic-history

In this [1929 paper by Stone](https://www.pnas.org/content/15/3/198), the 3rd citation is given as

> J. Von Neumann, *loci citati*; and an unpublished paper which is to appear in *Mathematische Annalen*, cf. *Göttinger Nachrichten*, 1927, pp. 1-55, footnotes 12 and 27.

I can't seem to find out what exactly "loci citati" means in this context and when/how it is expected to be used. More recently, this phrase was also used italicized in the 2nd section of a  [2012 paper by Znojil](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1257.pdf):

> The well known Coulomb – harmonic oscillator correspondence has been
> studied in [8]. In the role of a formal postulate it helped us to fix the physical
> asymptotic boundary conditions which would remain, otherwise, ambiguous
> (Ref. [12] and previous *loci citati* should be consulted for all details).

The previous citation in the first paper combined two works by Weyl and Von Neumann, in case there is some sort of reliance on other citations for it to have meaning.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loc._cit.. I think that in these LaTeX times it is no longer seen in maths papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Latin phrase meaning "[in the place cited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(L))".

I'm no Latin expert, but it doesn't seem like there's much significance in these phrases; they just redirect you to the given reference.

Comment: Going way out of my comfort zone here because I don't actually speak Latin: I believe, "loci citati" is plural, so it means "in the places cited". (My backyard Latin knowledge would suggest that "locus citatum" would have been singular?)

Comment: Going by my knowledge of Latin (few years in high school), “Loco citato” is ablative singular while loci citati is nominative plural. Looks like loco citato is the most popularly used one.

Comment: In secondary school, we learned to use "loc. cit." without worrying about which case or number it abbreviated. (But the use we made of it matched ablative singular.) Now that I'm a mathematician, I no longer need it.